# Starting geodjango

Tags: geodjango

I'm relatively new to programming but am solid on python & have the basics of django under my belt.  Now I'm trying to learn geodjango.

I went through the install process (on Windows XP) successfully following the instructions here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows

Now I want to go through the tutorial here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/

and the first thing it tells you to do is type:

```
$ createdb -T template_postgis geodjango
```

Do I type this at the command line? If I do that it tells me the standard message (not recognized as command, batch file etc...)  Do I need to put something in my path settings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't want to try installing geodjango on windows myself (Linux/Mac development is way more common, and you'll be able to find a lot more answers), but yes: you have to type

```
createdb.exe -T template_postgis geodjango
```

at the commandline. The createdb command is part of the PostgreSQL installation. I assume that if you installed the Postgres database correctly, Windows will put the directories with executable on the PATH.